# Unable to decode/encode Url properly

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm, url

I am working on a Url decoding and encoding system. But for some odd reason, it will only decode/encode certain string. Also, it seems to decode/encode a string when it has a certain piece in it. It is quite hard to explain but it is quite confusion as to what this might not work. I tried figuring out the problem of it but it just makes the whole issue seem more illogical than logical.

I hope someone can help me with this. With explanation to it. I would like it if the code is in the same style as it is as well.

I also know that there are probably some packages online to easily do that but I would rather just make my own. It's a way I can practice JS more.

```js
// I know I don't have all the characters markek. I am doing that later
var Url = {
  filterEncode : ["%2B","%3A","%3D","%3F","%2F","%26","%252F","%253A","%253D","%253F","%252B"],
  filterDecode : ["+",":","=","?","/","&","%2F","%3A","%3D","%3F","%2B"],
  decode : function(decodeText){
    let returnString, a, b;
    let filterEncode = Url.filterEncode;
    let filterDecode = Url.filterDecode;
    for (a = 0; a < filterEncode.length; a++){
      let regexEn = new RegExp(filterEncode[a],"g");
      let regexDe = new RegExp("/" + filterDecode[a],"g");
      let regex = new RegExp(regexEn,"g");
      let array = (decodeText.match(regex) || []).length
      for (b = 0; b < array; b++){
        returnString = decodeText.replace(filterEncode[a],filterDecode[a]);
        decodeText = returnString;
      }
    }
    return returnString;
  },
  encode : function(encodeText){
    let returnString, a, b;
    let filterEncode = Url.filterEncode;
    let filterDecode = Url.filterDecode;
    for (a = 0; a < filterEncode.length; a++){
      let regexEn = new RegExp("[" + filterEncode[2] + "]","g");
      let regexDe = new RegExp("[" + filterDecode[2] + "]","g");
      let regex = new RegExp(regexEn,"g");
      let array = (encodeText.match(regex) || []).length;
      for (b = 0; b < array; b++){
        returnString = encodeText.replace(filterDecode[a],filterEncode[a]);
        encodeText = returnString;
      }
    }
    return returnString;
  }
}

// Saying it is undefined
console.log(Url.encode("="));

// Encodes it just find
console.log(Url.encode("%3F"));

// Encodes both of them but for some odd reason encodes the
// equal sign twice.
console.log(Url.encode("%3F ="));
```

I do hope everything seems clear as to what my problem is about. I usually would just try searching on here for an answer, but this problem is so confusion, I don't know what I exactly should search for.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you concatenate `/` when creating `filterDecode`?

Comment: I was messing around with the Encode property more and was figuring out the problem. So that is why, it doesn't change anything however as I already tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your strings in `filterDecode` have special meaning as regular expressions. When converting the string to a regular expression, you need to wrap each character in `[]` so it will be matched literally.

You don't need to concatenate `/` when creating `regexDe`.

There's no need for the `for(b...)` loops. Use the regular expression in the `replace()` call and it will perform all the replacements at once, since it has the `g` flag.

Put the encode strings that contain `%` at the beginning of the array. Otherwise, when you encode something like `=` as `%3D`, a later iteration of the outer loop will re-encode that as `%253D`. You only want to encode this if it was in the original string, not an intermediate step.

```js
var Url = {
  filterDecode: ["%252F", "%253A", "%253D", "%253F", "%252B", "%2B", "%3A", "%3D", "%3F", "%2F", "%26"],
  filterEncode: ["%2F", "%3A", "%3D", "%3F", "%2B", "+", ":", "=", "?", "/", "&"],
  strToRe: function(str) {
    let reStr = str.split("").map(c => '[' + c + ']').join('');
    return new RegExp(reStr, "g");
  },
  decode: function(decodeText) {
    let a;
    let filterEncode = Url.filterEncode;
    let filterDecode = Url.filterDecode;
    for (a = 0; a < filterDecode.length; a++) {
      decodeText = decodeText.replace(Url.strToRe(filterDecode[a]), filterEncode[a]);
    }
    return decodeText;
  },
  encode: function(encodeText) {
    let a, b;
    let filterEncode = Url.filterEncode;
    let filterDecode = Url.filterDecode;
    for (a = 0; a < filterEncode.length; a++) {
      encodeText = encodeText.replace(Url.strToRe(filterEncode[a]), filterDecode[a]);
    }
    return encodeText;
  }
}

console.log(Url.encode("="));
console.log(Url.decode("%3D"));
console.log(Url.encode("%3F"));
console.log(Url.decode("%253F"));
console.log(Url.encode("%3F ="));
console.log(Url.decode("%253F %3D"));
```